# how to access activity variable into java class

Tags: java, android

in my android application i have a variable in my activity page like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);
        String pageTitle = "abc";
}
```

And i want to access this `pageTitle` variable into my java class like below:

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

        /**
         * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of {@code position}.
         */
        int getDividerColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;
    String value = "";
    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

And I want to access variable in this method

private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {//adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(pageTitle); // here I am putting `pageTitle` variable
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just make  `public static String pageTitle = "abc";` and used any where like `your_Activity.pageTitle`

Comment: pass the value to the constructor or create a setter in your java class

Comment: I want to use this variable into my java class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare PageTitle as static member of the activity and then use it in your java class as below:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{
    public static String pageTitle = "";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);
        pageTitle = "abc";
    } 
}
```

And in your java class

```
private void populateTabStrip() {
            ...
            tabTitleView.setText(MyActivity.pageTitle); 
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `String pageTitle = "abc";` created by you is the `Local Variable` of method `onCreate` as you have created it inside the method.

You need to declare it outside your `onCreate` if you want to use it outside the method.

Now depending upon your need, you can either declare `pageTitle` to be a `static` (class) variable and access it with the class name like, `YourActivityName.pageTitle` or you can pass the value of this `pageTitle` to the other class and hold it in any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for the SlidingTabLayout class, pass the parameter in there and set it after super.

Comment: that's quite a short answer. Would you care to elaborate a little, or maybe show some example code?